# Plone: cannot copy and paste News item from folder to collection

Tags: plone, zope

We are using Plone 4.1.3, and have problem copy/cut and paste News Item from a folder to a collection (of News Item).   We are getting this error when trying to paste the News items to the collection: Disallowed to paste item(s).   We checked all the permissions and they are okay.  Can somebody advise?

Thank you very much in anticipation.

cmgui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collections are designed to be queries, not containers for content.